# ionic Cordova appAvailability always return false

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

In my ionic app I need to check id facebook and twitter apps are installed on the device. To do so I installed AppAvailability and following the guidelines :

```html
let twitter = '';
let facebook = '';

if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
  twitter = 'twitter://';
  facebook = 'fb://';
} else if (this.plt.is('android')) {
  twitter = 'com.twitter.android';
  facebook = 'com.facebook.katana';
}

    this.appAvailability.check(twitter)
      .then(
        (yes: boolean) => this.isTwitterAvailable = true,
        (no: boolean) => this.isTwitterAvailable = false
      );
    this.appAvailability.check(facebook)
      .then(
        (yes: boolean) => this.isFacebookAvailable = true,
        (no: boolean) => this.isFacebookAvailable = false
      );
```

I always get "false" for both. The apps are installed. I tried inside the ionic dev apps and also with the real application on a realIOS device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw it in another answer somewhere, but it was something about making sure the plist was updated.  Here was the original answer, so if it works I can't take credit for knowing the answer, but hope it helps.

> edit the plist (platforms/ios/appname/appname-Info.plist) file for
>   your app and add facebook.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>facebook</string>
</array>
```

Someone had also noted it may be just

```
<string>fb</string>
```

in iOS11.  but haven't checked on that yet.

Comment: I confirm that this is working and the correct string to use is <string>fb</string>

Comment: Also, I think it is best to not touch the auto enerated plist file so I added this in my config.xml:         <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes">
            <array>
                <string>twitter</string>
                <string>fb</string>
                <string>instagram</string>
            </array>
        </edit-config>

Answer (score 2):

What I did following Indy-Jones answer:

```html
<platform name="ios">
...

  <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes"> 
    <array> 
      <string>twitter</string>
      <string>fb</string>
      <string>instagram</string>
    </array> 
  </edit-config>

....


</platform>
```

this will generate the entry inside the plist file. 
Note:

- in my case the plist wasn't updating. I removed and added the ios platform;
- this doesn't work using ionic dev app, you have to test it building the ios app.